# Lambda match condition in an attribute OR a sublist attribute of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, lambda

Hello I have the following lambda to get purchases that match certain conditions:

```
select = this.Model
    .Where(a => DateTime.Now.Subtract(a.CreateDate).TotalDays <= range)
    .Where(i => i.PayDate != DateTime.MinValue)
    .Where(x => x.Product.Equals(product) 
             || x.Items.Any(y => y.Type.Equals(product)));
```

The part that is giving me trouble is this one (as it works without it):

```
 || x.Items.Any(y => y.Type.Equals(product))
```

Inside a purchase I got a sublist of added products that are related to the main product, as I want to check the prices of those subitems I have to get in the result everything related to the actual product.

```
-Model(list)
   -Purchase(object)
       Product(ProductType)
       Price(float)
      -Items(list)
         -PurchaseItem(object)
             Type(ProductType)
             Price(float)
   -purc...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why type is `Type`? What "troubles" do you have, any exceptions?

Comment: Product and Type are the same custom type "ProductType", the value they are compared to also is a "ProductType"

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is `x.Product.Equals(product)`  always true for your data.

That means `x.Items.Any(y => y.Type.Equals(product))` never execute.

Comment: Debugged multiples times, is not the case

Answer (score 0):

To use .Equals() and other extension methods @ linq to compare objects (product in your case), you should implement the [IEquatable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1?view=net-7.0) interface on the product class.

This forces you to implement:

```
bool Equals(T x, T y);
int GetHashCode(T obj);
```

IEquatable is for an object of type T so that it can compare itself to another of the same type.

Why not compare the productId?

```
.Where(x => x.Product.Id == product.Id)
```